# Cant access value from the HTML dataset

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-dataset

I am using Dataset to get some different values when doing drag and drop from one div to another. but I am not able to access the additional attributes such as `data-customerId` when I call the Javascript function.

**HTML with PHP dynamic data:**

```
<fieldset id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Vacant parking spots</legend>
    <?php $counter = 0; foreach ($sql_get_vacant_spots_results_ as $row) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-customerid="<?php echo $arr_users[0]['customer_id']; ?>" data-y="<?php echo $row['spot_no'] ?>" data-z="<?php echo $row['location_id'] ?>" style="float: left; width: 120px;height: 80px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 20px;margin: 10px;background-color: cadetblue;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo 'Spot: ' . $row['spot_no'] . ' Gate: ' . $row['parking_gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php $counter++; } ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Current parking spots of the customer</legend>
    <?php $count = 0; foreach ($arr_users as $user) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $count ?>" data-customerid="<?php echo $user['customer_id'] ?>" data-y="<?php echo $user['spot_id'] ?>" data-z="<?php echo $user['location_id'] ?>" style="float: left; width: 120px;height: 80px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 20px;margin: 10px;background-color: cadetblue;" draggable="true" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo 'Spot: ' . $user['spot_id'] . ' Gate: ' .  $user['gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php $count++; } ?>
</fieldset>
```

**And here is the Javascript:**

```
   function drop(ev) {
        const el = document.querySelector('#' +ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")); //prints: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#33' is not a valid selector.
        console.log('drop', el.dataset.customerid);
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

Comment: Side note: If you are not married to the idea of vanilla javascript, you could save yourself lots of typing by using jquery :)

Answer (score -2):

**Fixed by accessing the id like this:**

```
const el = document.querySelector("[id=" + "\'" + ev.dataTransfer.getData("text") + "\'" + "]");
```

**EDIT:**

Html element id:

```
id="count_id<?php echo $counter; ?>"
```

Comment: Thats counter-intuitive. Given that `querySelector` takes a valid `#idname`. Your problem may stem from that your `id` are simply numbers, and thats going to just be problematic: "*ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").*"

Comment: @IncredibleHat I know. Check my Edit, I am adding text before the number id

Comment: Ah, I couldn't find the actual `id` value in your question code, so was curious! `id="<?php echo $counter; ?>"` looked like it was just the int.